# In Slick is there a way to declar Tables without using a Specific JDBC Driver

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, hsqldb, slick-2.0

In my persistence code all through out the tables, etc.  I have the following import

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
```

This is nice because it works, but this is a problem because all my code is bound to Postgres exclusively.  If I want my production to do Postgres and my test to be HSQLDB, for example, I can't.  I'd like to declare which DataSource/Driver when I'm running my persistence manager (which will do the create) instead of at the table declaration.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly possible using the cake pattern. My team uses H2 in development and MySQL in production.

See MultiDBExample and MultiDBCakeExample in https://github.com/slick/slick-examples

Comment: https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBExample.scala

Answer (score -2):

As far as I was able to find, I think this is a definite restriction in Slick. So much so that I dropped my test environments database and switched it to the same type as my production one. In retrospect, this is what I should have been doing in the first place, but I do understand this is sometimes easier said than done.