# In Slick 3.0 is there a way to declare Tables without using a Specific JDBC Driver

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

In slick 2.0 it was possible using something like this:

```
import driver.simple._
```

It was also asked here: [In Slick is there a way to declar Tables without using a Specific JDBC Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336441/in-slick-is-there-a-way-to-declar-tables-without-using-a-specific-jdbc-driver)

However this seems to be no longer case for Slick 3.0. In their upgrade guide there is:

> The JdbcDriver object has been deprecated. You should always use the
>   correct driver for your database system.
>    ~ http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/upgrade.html

But I still need to be able to switch between Postgress driver and H2. Is there anything I can do? 
For example is it possible to have the import-config in one place (for specific driver) and generic imports elsewhere. When I need to switch dbs, I just change import in one place. There may happen compilation errors because of driver switch but it's fine. But I don't want to go to every driver-related class and change the imports everytime I want to switch DB..

Comment: Take a look at [JdbcProfile](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.driver.JdbcProfile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the usual pattern is something like this.

```
object DriverRepository{
val defaultDriver: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("slick.dbs.default")
}
```

There you have a single place with a unique reference to the type of driver you want to use.

Then you will just need to:

```
import DriverRepository.defaultDriver.driver.api._
```

to access all your methods